# Generating configuration file in chef using 2 custom resources

Tags: chef

I would like to describe my server like

```
my-container("name")
my-feature("name", "config")
```

The my-container describes a docker container with some custom Dockerfile in name folder. When I add my-feature() to a server definition I would like an extra section to be added to Dockerfile while the rest of the file to be the same as my-container generated it.

How can I implement this or similar configuration in chef? I read about partials in chef templates, but not sure if they can be used in this situation.

Thank you,
Roman